# Project Slot Machine in Python

Tags: python, project

I am creating a slot machine using python and i don't have any idea how to print the slot machine but i want to print the slot machine from spin_slot_machine(symbols) there i have nine letters from symbol_count who were randomly chosen. For example if this is output from parameter columns of spin_slot_machine(symbols)-->['A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'B'] i want to make like that like this ex:

[image]

```
import random 
MAX_VALUE = 100
MIN_VALUE = 1
ROWS = 3
COLUMNS = 3

symbols_count = {
    "A":2,
    "B":4,
    "C":3,
    "E":3,
    "F":2
}

def spin_slot_machine(symbols):
    all_symbols = []
    columns = []
    length_of_spin = 9
    for symbol,symbol_count in symbols.items():
        for i in range(symbol_count):
            all_symbols.append(symbol)
    for i in range(length_of_spin):
        get_random = random.choice(all_symbols)
        columns.append(get_random)
    return columns 
def print_slot_machine(columns):
    pass




        





def deposit():
    while True:
        deposit_money = input("How much money would you like to deposit?: $")
        if deposit_money.isdigit():
            deposit_money = int(deposit_money)
            if deposit_money > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("You should deposit more than 0$")
        print("Enter a digit")
    return deposit_money 
def bet_on_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input("On how many lines would you like to bet(1-3)?: ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if lines >= 1 and lines <= 3:
                break
            else:
                print("Number of lines should be between 1-3")
        print("Enter a number of lines")
    return lines


def get_bet():
    while True:
        bet = input("How much money would you like to bet(1$-100$): ")
        if bet.isdigit():
            bet = int(bet)
            if bet <= MAX_VALUE and bet >= MIN_VALUE:
                break
            else:
                print("Money should be between 1-100$")
        else:
            print("Enter a digit")
    return bet 


def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines_number = bet_on_lines()
    while True:
        bet_money = get_bet()
        total_bet = bet_money * lines_number 
        if total_bet > balance:
            print(f"Your balance is {balance}$.Balance shoudn't be less than betting money , bet less!")
        else:
            break
    print(f"You are betting {total_bet}$ on {lines_number} lines.")
    slot_machine = spin_slot_machine(symbols_count)
    print_slot_machine(slot_machine)

main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i think i defined but i want to make the print_slot_machine like the picture,i should take the output from spin_slot_machine these are like random symbols who where chosen with random module and from that list to make like the picture run the code it will give you better idea what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to print them you can use something like this:

```
symbols = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'B']
print(' | '.join(symbols[0:3]))
print(' | '.join(symbols[3:6]))
print(' | '.join(symbols[6:9]))
```

It will give you what you wanted

Comment: the same thing `for i in range(0, len(symbols),3): print(' | '.join(symbols[i:i+3]))`